# remove/replace Unicode characters javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
<span class="X">(&#8237;−&#8237;500&#8236;&#8236;</span>
```

I get the innerHTML from this span: var abc = document.querySelector("SELECTOR").innerHTML

It shows as "(-500" but when I copy it to the notepad it comes with the a invisible Unicode, how can I get the innerHTML just as simple text "-500" but without the Unicode and without the "(".

Comment: Who is inserting this text into the span ?

Comment: note that all characters are unicode. these are just entities.

Comment: I'm scraping with puppeteer/nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly remove the invisible Unicode characters and convert some Unicode characters into their ASCII equivalents:

```
let x = document.querySelector('.x').innerHTML;
x = x.replace(/\u202d/g, '');  // (0x202d = 8237 "LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE")
x = x.replace(/\u2212/g, '-'); // (0x2212 = 8277 "MINUS SIGN")
```

Comment: This is great, x = x.replace(/\u202d/g, '') and x = x.replace(/\u202c/g, '') replace the &#8237 and &#8236, is this possible to put in only one replace ?

Comment: This works somehow for what i need :D : x = x.replace(/\u202c|\u202d|\(/g, ''); thank you!