# parseInt returns NaN for normal-looking numeric strings. Why?

Tags: javascript, unicode, nan, parseint, bidi

So I have the JSON below, as an example:

```json
[{"x":"‭12‬","y":"‭−‭67‬‬"},{"x":"‭12‬","y":"‭−‭68‬‬"},{"x":"‭13‬","y":"‭−‭70‬‬"}]
```

After I parse it into an object, using `JSON.parse`, I end up with an array of objects. So far so good. But when I try to parse those "x" and "y" coordinates into integers, I just get `NaN` no matter what! Tried all kinds of solutions; `parseInt(obj.x)`, `+obj.x`, `Number(obj.x)`, etc..! Just can't understand why I can't convert those properties to integers?

Comment: You say you ran `parseInt(obj.x)` - but which element in the array (1st, 2nd, or 3rd?) is `obj` referring to? Or is `obj` the array itself? (Also, `parseInt` should always be used with the radix parameter - though I don't know if that's relevant here)

Comment: did u use map and process each elemet

Comment: There are some 202D characters before the number

Comment: @cmgchess `map` should not be used for "processing" elements - use `for(of)` if you're inducing side-effects. `map` is an FP method intended for non-destructive changes to immutable data by applying changes to a new separate return array).

Comment: First, try to get a value of an index : let say ``` console.log(parseInt(obj[0].x)) ```; Right now as i see you are not referring the object itself, you refer to the array.

Comment: @adiga So, if that's true, how do I get rid of those, so I can do the parse??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357971/remove-replace-unicode-characters-javascript

Comment: The better question might be on how these characters ended up being there.

Comment: You have to fix the source of the JSON. If that is not in yor control, you'd have to use regex

Comment: `const x = parseInt(item.x.replace('\u202d', ''))` etc. But @adiga is right, you need to fix the JSON source

Comment: That `-` sign charcode is 2212. So, you'd have to do something like: `parseInt(some.y.replace(/−/, '-').replace(/[^-\d.]/g, ''))` But, better to fix the source to return valid numbers. Paste the string in any unicode inspector like: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect

Comment: @adiga Yes, the positive numbers are now working! But the negative ones still show NaN... I tried `.replace('\u2212', '-')`, but that didn't work :/

Comment: @adiga Thanks for the tip on the unicode inspect website. I think I can figure it out now!

Comment: `parseInt(obj.y.replace(/−/, '-').replace(/[^-\d.]/g, ''))`works. The first `replace` replaces the 2212 char with the ascii hyphen `-`

Comment: Here is your data `[{
  x: "%u202D12%u202C",
  y: "%u202D%u2212%u202D67%u202C%u202C"
}, {
  x: "%u202D12%u202C",
  y: "%u202D%u2212%u202D68%u202C%u202C"
}, {
  x: "%u202D13%u202C",
  y: "%u202D%u2212%u202D70%u202C%u202C"
}]`

Comment: @fduayer glad you got it working. But you really need to focus on where those characters came from and getting rid of them.

Comment: @Nick Unfortunately, that's out of my control, so I'll just have to deal with it. But it's working now! Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your numeric strings contain invisible Unicode formatting (directional override) characters.  Furthermore, the minus signs are true typographical minus signs (U+2212) instead of the typewriter hyphen-minus characters (U+002D), and `parseInt` is unable to parse the former.

```text
offset       USV  gc  sc    bc     age  name
[...]
     6    U+0022  Po  Zyyy  ON     1.1  QUOTATION MARK
     7    U+202D  Cf  Zyyy  LRO    1.1  LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
    10    U+0031  Nd  Zyyy  EN     1.1  DIGIT ONE
    11    U+0032  Nd  Zyyy  EN     1.1  DIGIT TWO
    12    U+202C  Cf  Zyyy  PDF    1.1  POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
    15    U+0022  Po  Zyyy  ON     1.1  QUOTATION MARK
[...]
    21    U+0022  Po  Zyyy  ON     1.1  QUOTATION MARK
    22    U+202D  Cf  Zyyy  LRO    1.1  LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
    25    U+2212  Sm  Zyyy  ES     1.1  MINUS SIGN
    28    U+202D  Cf  Zyyy  LRO    1.1  LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
    31    U+0036  Nd  Zyyy  EN     1.1  DIGIT SIX
    32    U+0037  Nd  Zyyy  EN     1.1  DIGIT SEVEN
    33    U+202C  Cf  Zyyy  PDF    1.1  POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
    36    U+202C  Cf  Zyyy  PDF    1.1  POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
    39    U+0022  Po  Zyyy  ON     1.1  QUOTATION MARK
[...]
```

Ideally, you would fix the JSON so that it contain numbers directly (instead of wrapped in strings).  But if that is outside your control, you need to remove the formatting characters and replace the minus sign with the hyphen-minus before using `parseInt`.

```js
const parseScrapedInt = (s) => {
  s = s.replaceAll(/\p{Cf}/ug, '');
  s = s.replaceAll(/\u{2212}/ug, '\u{002d}');
  return parseInt(s, 10);
};

console.log(parseScrapedInt("\u{202d}12\u{202c}"));
console.log(parseScrapedInt("\u{202d}−\u{202d}67\u{202c}\u{202c}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot change the data, then try this:

```js
const makeNum = str => {
  let sign = escape(str).includes("%u2212%u202D") ? -1 : 1;
  return str.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu, "") * sign;
};

const numCoordinates = coordinates
  .map(({ x, y }) => ({ x: makeNum(x), y: makeNum(y) }));

console.log(numCoordinates);
```

```html
Data received:

<pre>
[{ x: "%u202D12%u202C", y: "%u202D%u2212%u202D67%u202C%u202C" }, 
 { x: "%u202D12%u202C", y: "%u202D%u2212%u202D68%u202C%u202C" }, 
 { x: "%u202D13%u202C", y: "%u202D%u2212%u202D70%u202C%u202C" }] 
</pre>
<script>
  const coordinates = [{
    "x": "‭12‬",
    "y": "‭−‭67‬‬"
  }, {
    "x": "‭12‬",
    "y": "‭−‭68‬‬"
  }, {
    "x": "‭13‬",
    "y": "‭−‭70‬‬"
  }];
</script>
```